# Why is ReversedLinesFileReader so slow?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-commons-io

I have a file that is 21.6GB and I want to read it from the end to the start rather than from the beginning to the end as you would usually do.

If I read each line of the file from the start to the end using the following code, then it takes 1 minute, 12 seconds.

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
File("very-large-file.xml").forEachLine {
    val i = 0
}
val diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
println(diff.timeFormat())
```

Now, I have read that to read in a file in reverse then I should use `ReversedLinesFileReader` from Apache Commons.  I have created the following extension function to do just this:

```
fun File.forEachLineFromTheEndOfFile(action: (line: String) -> Unit) {
    val reader = ReversedLinesFileReader(this, Charset.defaultCharset())
    var line = reader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        action.invoke(line)
        line = reader.readLine()
    }

    reader.close()
}
```

and then call it in the following way, which is the same as the previous way only with a call to `forEachLineFromTheEndOfFile` function:

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
File("very-large-file.xml").forEachLineFromTheEndOfFile {
    val i = 0
}
val diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
println(diff.timeFormat())
```

This took **17 minutes and 50 seconds** to run!

- Am I using `ReversedLinesFileReader` in the correct way?
- I am running Linux Mint with an Ext4 file system on an SSD.  Could this have anything to do with it?
- Is it just the case that files should not be read from the end to the start?

Comment: Do you know what the data looks like? How uniform are the line breaks?

Comment: @BrianKent, I'm not sure what you mean by how uniform the line breaks are but the data in question is an XML file from the OpenStreetMap project.

Comment: Are you sure you need to process the file in reverse order? I suspect you would be better off reading the lines in their natural order and saving off chunks of data to temporary files and/or a database and then processing the data in this intermediary format which if chunked into smaller files and/or with a database can then easily be processed in reverse order.

Comment: Hang on, how can you read XML back to front?

Comment: I wrote a new one reverse file reader that is around 4x slower then reading forward instead of the 17x you encountered.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39583921/3679676

Comment: @mfulton26 - I don't strictly need to read it in reverse order.  The OSM file is constructed of relations, ways and nodes. I know which relations I want based upon certain criterea.  Each relation has a number of Ways IDs. I can then lookup each Way I'm interested in based on ID, these then contain a list of Nodes. Then I can look up Nodes based upon IDs.  This all works at the moment by parsing three times, but I thought I might be able to read the file in backwards as that might save time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a very expensive operation.  Not only are you using random access in blocks to read the file and going backwards (so if the file system is reading ahead, it is reading the wrong direction), you are also reading an XML file which is UTF-8 and the encoding is slower than a fixed byte encoding.

Then on top of that you are using a less than efficient algorithm.  It reads a block at a time of inconvenient size  (is it disk block size aware? are you setting the block size to match your file system?) backwards while processing encoding and makes (unnecessary?) copy of the partial byte array and then turns it into a string (do you need a string to parse?).  It could create the string without the copy and really creating the string probably could be deferred and you work directly from the buffer only decoding if you need to (XML parsers for example also work from ByteArrays or buffers).  And there are other array copies that just are not needed but it is more convenient for the code.

It also  might have a bug in that it checks for newlines without considering that the character might mean something different if actually is part of a multi-byte sequence.  It would have to look back a few extra characters to check this for variable length encodings, I don't see it doing that.

So instead of a nice forward only heavily buffered sequential read of a file which is the fastest thing you can do on your filesystem, you are doing random reads of 1 block at a time.  It should at least read multiple disk blocks so that it can use the forward momentum (set blocksize to some multiple of your disk block size will help) and also avoid the number of "left over" copies made at buffer boundaries.

There are probably faster approaches.  But it'll not be as fast as reading a file in forward order.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I tried an experiment with a rather silly version that processes around 27G of data by reading the first 10 million lines from wikidata JSON dump and reversing those lines.

Timings on my 2015 Mac Book Pro (with all my dev stuff and many chrome windows open eating memory and some CPU all the time, about 5G of total memory is free, VM size is default with no parameters set at all, not run under debugger):

```
reading in reverse order: 244,648 ms = 244 secs = 4 min 4 secs
reading in forward order:  77,564 ms =  77 secs = 1 min 17 secs

temp file count:   201
approx char count: 29,483,478,770 (line content not including line endings)
total line count:  10,050,000
```

The algorithm is to read the original file by lines buffering 50000 lines at a time, writing the lines in reverse order to a numbered temp file.  Then after all files are written, they are read in reverse numerical order forward by lines.  Basically dividing them into reverse sort order fragments of the original.  It could be optimized because this is the most naive version of that algorithm with no tuning.  But it does do what file systems do best, sequential reads and sequential writes with good sized buffers.

So this is a lot faster than the one you were using and it could be tuned from here to be more efficient.  You could trade CPU for disk I/O size and try using gzipped files as well, maybe a two threaded model to have the next buffer gzipping while processing the previous.  Less string allocations, checking each file function to make sure nothing extra is going on, make sure no double buffering, and more.

The ugly but functional code is:

```
package com.stackoverflow.reversefile

import java.io.File
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val maxBufferSize = 50000
    val lineBuffer = ArrayList<String>(maxBufferSize)
    val tempFiles = ArrayList<File>()
    val originalFile = File("/data/wikidata/20150629.json")
    val tempFilePrefix = "/data/wikidata/temp/temp"
    val maxLines = 10000000

    var approxCharCount: Long = 0
    var tempFileCount = 0
    var lineCount = 0

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    println("Writing reversed partial files...")

    try {
        fun flush() {
            val bufferSize = lineBuffer.size
            if (bufferSize > 0) {
                lineCount += bufferSize
                tempFileCount++
                File("$tempFilePrefix-$tempFileCount").apply {
                    bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
                        ((bufferSize - 1) downTo 0).forEach { idx ->
                            writer.write(lineBuffer[idx])
                            writer.newLine()
                        }
                    }
                    tempFiles.add(this)
                }
                lineBuffer.clear()
            }

            println("  flushed at $lineCount lines")
        }

        // read and break into backword sorted chunks
        originalFile.bufferedReader(bufferSize = 4096 * 32)
                .lineSequence()
                .takeWhile { lineCount <= maxLines }.forEach { line ->
                    lineBuffer.add(line)
                    if (lineBuffer.size >= maxBufferSize) flush()
                }
        flush()

        // read backword sorted chunks backwards
        println("Reading reversed lines ...")
        tempFiles.reversed().forEach { tempFile ->
            tempFile.bufferedReader(bufferSize = 4096 * 32).lineSequence()
                .forEach { line ->
                    approxCharCount += line.length
                    // a line has been read here
                }
            println("  file $tempFile current char total $approxCharCount")
        }
    } finally {
        tempFiles.forEach { it.delete() }
    }

    val elapsed =  System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime

    println("temp file count:   $tempFileCount")
    println("approx char count: $approxCharCount")
    println("total line count:  $lineCount")
    println()
    println("Elapsed:  ${elapsed}ms  ${elapsed / 1000}secs  ${elapsed / 1000 / 60}min  ")

    println("reading original file again:")
    val againStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var againLineCount = 0
    originalFile.bufferedReader(bufferSize = 4096 * 32)
            .lineSequence()
            .takeWhile { againLineCount <= maxLines }
            .forEach { againLineCount++ }
    val againElapsed =  System.currentTimeMillis() - againStartTime
    println("Elapsed:  ${againElapsed}ms  ${againElapsed / 1000}secs  ${againElapsed / 1000 / 60}min  ")
}
```

Comment: It is impossible for UTF-8 multi-byte sequences to look like a new line. UTF-8 was specifically designed to have no representation of non-ASCII characters that look like ASCII bytes. The `ReversedLinesFileReader` is exploiting that property. So there’s no bug.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to investigate this problem would be:

1. Write a version of this test in pure Java.
2. Benchmark it to make sure that the performance problem is still there.
3. Profile it to figure out where the performance bottleneck is.

---

> Q: Am I using ReversedLinesFileReader in the correct way?

Yes.  (Assuming that it is an appropriate thing to use a line reader at all.  That depends on what it is you are really trying to do.  For instance, if you just wanted to count lines backwards, then you should be reading 1 character at a time and counting the newline sequences.)

> Q: I am running Linux Mint with an Ext4 file system on an SSD. Could this have anything to do with it?

Possibly.  Reading a file in reverse means that the read-ahead strategies used by the OS to give fast I/O may not work.  It could be interacting with the characteristics of an SSD.

> Q: Is it just the case that files should not be read from the end to the start?

Possibly.  See above.

---

The other thing that you have not considered is that your file could actually contain some extremely long lines.  The bottleneck *could* be the assembly of the characters into (long) lines.

Looking at the [source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html), it would seem that there is potential for `O(N^2)` behavior when lines are very long.  The critical part is (I think) in the way that "rollover" is handled by `FilePart`.  Note the way that the "left over" data gets copied.